# How mock a instance of File in Dart

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, dart, mockito

I want mock the method `file.writeAsBytes`, but I don't know how to make this.

note: I do not intend to save the files in the test, just overwrite the method so that I can get the list of paths.

Has anyone ever experienced this?

**My code is**

```
class ShareHelper {

  static Future<List<String>> createFilesFromString(
          List<FileShare> files) async =>
      Future.wait(
          files.map((fileShare) => _createFileFromString(fileShare)).toList());

  static Future<String> _createFileFromString(FileShare fileShare) async {
    final str = fileShare.base64.split(',');
    Uint8List bytes = base64.decode(str[1]);
    String dir = (await getTemporaryDirectory()).path;

    final fileName = _createFileName(fileShare.name);

    File file = File(
        "$dir/" + fileName);
    await file.writeAsBytes(bytes);
    return file.path;
  }
}
```

**My unit test:**

```
    test('Deve compartilhar os arquivos', () async {
      PathProviderPlatform.instance = MockPathProviderPlatform();

      final files = [
        FileShare(name: 'Teste/A', base64: 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUg...'),
      ];

      final paths = await ShareHelper.createFilesFromString(files);
      expect(paths, []);
    });

  });
```

Comment: I highly recommend not using using `File` from `dart:io` directly and instead use the [`package:file`](https://pub.dev/packages/file).  That will allow you to use `MemoryFileSystem` in tests.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Mockito](https://pub.dev/packages/mockito)` mocking package, so you can easily mock the File and override the desired methods with fake responses.

```
  class MockFile extends Mock implements File {
  @override
  Future<File> writeAsBytes(List<int> bytes, {FileMode mode = FileMode.write, bool flush = false}) {
    // TODO: implement writeAsBytes
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }
}
```